# DQL Queries not functionning (Doctrine2; Symfony5.0)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm having trouble with DQL queries on a project I'm working on. What the DQL is supposed to do is find in the DB all the datas that are related to a productLine variable; that a user would type and search for into a form.

My issue is when I run a test with a product Line; I get an "Error 500" thrown; and I know the error origins from the Repository file; since the controller works fine (I've added some var_dumps in the controller after the query's line to check and I'm not reaching it when testing with the faulty function, whereas with another working function I can reach it).

I know that the data typed in by the user is collected (the product Line entered by the user), there seems to be an issue with DQL processing the query that I can't seem to find an answer for anywhere.

Without further ado; here's the code.

**Working fine query**

```
public function findByLotNumber($lotNumber){
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->distinct()
    ->where('u.lotNumber LIKE :lotNumberS')
    ->setParameter('lotNumberS', $lotNumber . '%')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult(); 
    
}
```

**faulty query**

```
public function findByCriteriaIdentification($criteriaIdentification){
    $givenLotNumber = $_POST['lotNumber'];
    if(empty($_POST['lotNumber'])){
        $givenLotNumber = '%';
    }
    
    $givenProductLine = $_POST['productLine'];
    if(empty($_POST['productLine'])){
        $givenProductLine = '%';
    }
    
$varTest = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->distinct()
    ->where('u.lotNumber LIKE :lotNumberS')
    ->orWhere('u.productLine LIKE :productLineS')
    ->setParameter('lotNumberS', $givenLotNumber)
    ->setParameter('productLineS', $givenProductLine);
    $queryTest = $varTest->getQuery();
    return $queryTest->execute();
}
```

Does anyone have an insight regarding what I'm coding wrong ?
PS: this being a corporate project I don't have the possibility of upgrading to Symfo 6 or Doctrine3 at the moment.

EDIT: Here's the class of the entity i'm querying:

```
    namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\WafRepository")
 */
class Waf extends Sil
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Sil")
     */    
    
    private $id; 

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $rankId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $size;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $thickness;
    
    

    
    /*public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }*/

    public function getRankId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->rankId;
    }

    public function setRankId(int $rankId): self
    {
        $this->rankId = $rankId;

        return $this;
    }
    
    public function getSize(): ?int
    {
        return $this->size;
    }

    public function setSize(int $size): self
    {
        $this->size = $size;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getThickness(): ?int
    {
        return $this->thickness;
    }

    public function setThickness(?int $thickness): self
    {
            $this->thickness = $thickness;
    
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

In case its useful, I'm adding as well the class "sili" that waf is an extent from:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SiliconRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="silType", type="string")
 
 */
class Sil
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    private $lotNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=80, nullable=true)
     */
    private $productLine;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $productCode;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $productLineCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $sourceLot;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $division;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    //private $comment;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $testStatus;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    //private $lastUpdate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $maturity;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Operations", mappedBy="silicon")
     */
    private $operations;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\State", mappedBy="silicon")
     */
    private $states;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $fatherLotNumber;

   


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->operations = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->states = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLotNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lotNumber;
    }

    public function setLotNumber(string $lotNumber): self
    {
        $this->lotNumber = $lotNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProductLine(): ?string
    {
        return $this->productLine;
    }

    public function setProductLine(?string $productLine): self
    {
        $this->productLine = $productLine;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProductCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->productCode;
    }

    public function setProductCode(?string $productCode): self
    {
        $this->productCode = $productCode;

        return $this;
    }
    
    public function getProductLineCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->productLineCode;
    }
    
    public function setProductLineCode(?string $productLineCode): self
    {
        $this->productLineCode = $productLineCode;
        
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSourceLot(): ?string
    {
        return $this->sourceLot;
    }

    public function setSourceLot(?string $sourceLot): self
    {
        $this->sourceLot = $sourceLot;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDivision(): ?int
    {
        return $this->division;
    }

    public function setDivision(?int $division): self
    {
        $this->division = $division;

        return $this;
    }

    /*public function getComment(): ?string
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    public function setComment(?string $comment): self
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }*/

    public function getTestStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->testStatus;
    }

    public function setTestStatus(?string $testStatus): self
    {
        $this->testStatus = $testStatus;

        return $this;
    }

    /*public function getLastUpdate(): ?int
    {
        return $this->lastUpdate;
    }

    public function setLastUpdate(int $lastUpdate): self
    {
        $this->lastUpdate = $lastUpdate;

        return $this;
    }*/

    public function getMaturity(): ?int
    {
        return $this->maturity;
    }

    public function setMaturity(?int $maturity): self
    {
        $this->maturity = $maturity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Operations[]
     */
    public function getOperations(): Collection
    {
        return $this->operations;
    }

    public function addOperation(Operations $operation): self
    {
        while (!($this)->operations->contains($operation)) {
            $this->operations[] = $operation;
            $operation->setSilicon($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeOperation(Operations $operation): self
    {        
        if ($this->operations->contains($operation)) {
            $this->operations->removeElement($operation);
            //$this->reformatTab($this->operations);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($operation->getSilicon() === $this) {
                $operation->setSilicon(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|State[]
     */
    public function getStates(): Collection
    {
        return $this->states;
    }

    public function addState(State $state): self
    {
        if (!$this->states->contains($state)) {
            $this->states[] = $state;
            $state->setSilicon($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeState(State $state): self
    {
        if ($this->states->contains($state)) {
            $this->states->removeElement($state);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($state->getSilicon() === $this) {
                $state->setSilicon(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFatherLotNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->fatherLotNumber;
    }

    public function setFatherLotNumber(?string $fatherLotNumber): self
    {
        $this->fatherLotNumber = $fatherLotNumber;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you add the class of the entity you're querying? Also the logs of the error 500 could be of great help

Comment: @Maniax sure thing, added the class and the class it extends to the post

Comment: Assuming you're in the right repo, it should work. Did you already checked the SQL table and passed validate-schema ?

Comment: Can you get a Exception trace or something that includes a little bit more detail? On a whim I would say that the query cannot be parsed, probably due to a parameter having an unexpected value, using `$_POST` directly seems a bit smelly to me.